# Unknown custom element: <my-company-form-extra> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, directive

I am trying to render a component with the is directive

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-tabs v-model="currentTab" fixed-tabs>
      <v-tab v-for="(item, i) in tabItems" :key="i">{{ item }} </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
    <v-form ref="form" v-model="isValid" lazy-validation>
      <v-tabs-items v-model="currentTab">
        <v-tab-item v-for="(item, i) in tabItems" :key="i">
          <component :is="'my-company-form-general'"></component>
          <my-company-form-general />
        </v-tab-item>
      </v-tabs-items>
    </v-form>
  </div>
</template>
```

This works `<my-company-form-general />`

but this doesn't

```
<component :is="'my-company-form-general'"></component>
```

I also tried by file name

```
<component :is="'MyCompantFormGeneral'"></component>
```

Why doesn't it work?

I'm using nuxt v2.14.6

The component is called `MyCompanyFormGeneral.vue` and it is in the same folder

```
<template>
    <div>
        General Component
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue'

    export default Vue.extend({

    })
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Are you using `components: true` in your `nuxt.config.js`, or are you manually importing your components in your component?

Comment: I have components set to true in my nuxt config

Comment: please do not bind if you dont really need it `is="my-company-form-general"`

Answer (score 1):

When using `components: true` nuxt will look through your pages and components and import all the components you used automatically.

When using dynamic components (`<component is="..." />`) it doesn't know what to import and you will have to import the components you will use with it manually:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyCompantFormGeneral from '~/components/your-path/your-component-here.vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  components: {
    MyCompantFormGeneral
  }
})
```

I hope this fixes your issue.